# Prevent directory permissions of sites/default from being protected in a local environment?

Tags: configuration, files

Drupal automatically changes the directory permissions of `sites/default` to 555 (i.e. read-only), which means that if I'm editing `sites/default/settings.php`, even if I've set the permissions for that file to read/write (which it again reverts on a page load), PhpStorm still gives me a permission denied error on the **swap** file it's attempting to create in the same directory.

- Is there a more flexible way to update settings (especially on
  a dev machine) other than manually setting the file and directory
  permissions every time you need to edit those files?
- Do I just have to do it via sudo?
- Can I disable permissions checking for a specific environment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are on Drupal 8, you can configure settings.php to include a settings.local.php with a simple environment check (to ensure you are running a local env).

In that file, you can add this:

`$settings['skip_permissions_hardening'] = TRUE;`

This will allow you to open and write to settings.php without it being locked back down.

Comment: Thanks - I'll add that this is included in the default settings of  `example.settings.local.php`

Comment: along with this, I needed to make sure the owner was myself. example: sudo chown -R username rootdir

Answer (score -3):

Filezilla allowed me to change the permissions from the the Filezilla console when cpanel could not [Drupal Docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/install/step-3-create-settingsphp-and-the-files-directory)

Comment: This isn't a question about cpanel permissions.